# java scanner to detect 3 words on line

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write a little program that will use scanner to check if there is a next line (in awhile loop) and then maybe another one to check that the words on the line are tab appart and there are 3 strings (the use constructor to create a object) so the three strings would be Product Name Manufacturer Brcode

EG:  Tyre17x60    Goodyear    458765464

and so and so

I am bit stuck with this so any help would be grateful

Comment: Post your code.. We can't read minds.

Comment: What's your exact problem doing this? What have your tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    String str = "Tyre17x60 Goodyear 458765464"; 
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(is);
    sc.useDelimiter("\n");

    while (sc.hasNext())
    {         
      String[] tmp = sc.next().split("\t");
      if (tmp.length == 3)
         System.out.println("Text contains 3 parts separated with tabs");              
      else
        System.out.println("Text is not well formated");

      // save data 
      //productName = tmp[0];
      //manufacturer = tmp[1];
      //brcode = tmp[2];

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are reading from a file, you can use the following code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
while(s.hasNext())
{
    String productName = s.next();
    String Manufacturer = s.next();
    String Brcode = s.next();
}
```

Comment: if you have a file of 100 products and one is missing the barcode then the name of the product will be read and then the whole thing will not make sense!

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner("file.txt");
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Product : " + scan.next());
            System.out.println("Name : " + scan.next());
            System.out.println("Code : " + scan.nextLong());

        }
```

Try something like this....